# Is it possible to access App's version from library project in Spring(with maven)?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, version, library-project

I'm working on a spring (with maven) custom library project. I can access my library project's version ( say 3.0-SNAPSHOT). 
How can I access App's version from library project?
I mean the version of the app that uses my custom library project as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Of course.
First, you need set up nexus server for use.
Second, you deploy your app to your private nexus server.
You can search maven nexus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The easiest way I found was to introduce a new configuration value in your application.properties like so

`whatever.value.name=@project.version@`

and use it from within your classes like this

```
@Value("${whatever.value.name:none}")
private String projectVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your library project references the App root module as a parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>app.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

You can then reference the `project.version` property of the app parent in your library with `${project.version}` - just make sure you don't have a version defined in the library project otherwise it will use that. If you do want to have a separate library version you can add a property in the parent:

```
<properties>
    <app.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</app.version>
</properties>
```

and reference it in the library with `${app.version}`